# Merge 2 dictionaries except one column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 dictionaries and I try to merge both in single one (only problem is that in both `p` and `config` I have id column). I tried like this only thing is that I need to update p with config but I want to keep `id` of `p` not `id` of `config`

```
new_p = p.copy() 
new_p.update(config)
```

Please help me. Thx in advance

Comment: How have you approached this problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you please show dummy examples of your two dictionaries? The formatting of your question makes it difficult to understand what you need.

Comment: Update `p` with  `config` but keep `id` value of `p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
id_value = p['id']
p.update(config)
p['id'] = id_value
```

Store the value of id from p in a separate variable and use it after you update p with values from config.

Comment: @George if it is the right answer you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

To update p with config but keep id value of p

```
new_p = dict(p, **dict(config, id=p['id'])
```